# Nim inter-thread message passing: How to avoid a global TChannel?

Tags: concurrency, nim-lang

I have the following simple example of an inter-thread communication problem: I want to run arbitrary "anytime" algorithms in a background thread. An anytime algorithm performs some computation of result type `T` incrementally, i.e., it sporadically produces newer, more precise results. In Nim parlance, they are probably best represented by an iterator. In the main thread, I now want to wrap such iterators each in its own thread, with the possibility to query the threads for things like "is there a new value available" or "what is the current computation result".

Since I'm not familiar with Nim's concurrency concepts I have trouble to implement the required inter-thread communication. My idea was to use a `TChannel` for the communication. According to [this forum post](http://forum.nim-lang.org/t/959), a `TChannel` cannot be used in combination with `spawn` but requires to use `createThread`. I managed to get the following to compile and run:

```
import os, threadpool

proc spawnBackgroundJob[T](f: iterator (): T): TChannel[T] =

  type Args = tuple[iter: iterator (): T, channel: ptr TChannel[T]]

  # I think I have to wrap the iterator to pass it to createThread
  proc threadFunc(args: Args) {.thread.} =
    echo "Thread is starting"
    let iter = args.iter
    var channel = args.channel[]

    for i in iter():
      echo "Sending ", i
      channel.send(i)

  var thread: TThread[Args]
  var channel: TChannel[T]
  channel.open()

  let args = (f, channel.addr)
  createThread(thread, threadFunc, args)

  result = channel


# example use in some main thread:
iterator test(): int {.closure.} =
  sleep(500)
  yield 1
  sleep(500)
  yield 2

var channel = spawnBackgroundJob[int](test)

for i in 0 .. 10:
  sleep(200)
  echo channel.peek()

echo "Finished"
```

Unfortunately, this does not have the expected behavior, i.e., I never receive anything in the main thread. I was told on IRC that the problem is that I do not use global variables. But even after a long time thinking I neither do see exactly why this fails, nor if there is a way to solve it. The problem is that I cannot simply make the variables `thread` and `channel` global, since they depend on the type `T`. I also want to avoid restricting this to only run a single anytime algorithm (or some other fixed number N). I was also told that the approach does not really make sense overall, so maybe I'm just missing that this problem has an entirely different solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Reason:

**You're using two different channels in send and recv**.

object assign in Nim is deep copy, they're different object.

```
var channel = args.channel[]
```

and

```
result = channel
```

To explain it, see code snippet below:

```
type
  A = object
    x: int
    y: int

var a,b: A

var c = cast[ptr A](allocShared0(sizeof(A))) # shared memory allocation

a = c[]
b = c[]

echo a.x, a.y, b.x, b.y, c.x, c.y # output: 000000

a.x = 1
a.y = 2

echo a.x, a.y, b.x, b.y, c.x, c.y # output: 120000

b.x = 3
b.y = 4

echo a.x, a.y, b.x, b.y, c.x, c.y # output: 123400
```

---

### Solution to pass channel in and out proc:

To pass Channel as parameter and return value, please refer to Jehan's Answer in [Nim forum](http://forum.nim-lang.org/t/1572/2).

paste Jehan's Answer here for quick reference, and make it compile pass in Nim 0.11.2

```
type SharedChannel[T] = ptr TChannel[T]

proc newSharedChannel[T](): SharedChannel[T] =
  result = cast[SharedChannel[T]](allocShared0(sizeof(TChannel[T])))
  open(result[])

proc close[T](ch: var SharedChannel[T]) =
  close(ch[])
  deallocShared(ch)
  ch = nil

proc send[T](ch: SharedChannel[T], content: T) =
  ch[].send(content)


proc recv[T](ch: SharedChannel[T]): T =
  result = ch[].recv

proc someThread(ch: (SharedChannel[string], SharedChannel[bool])) {.thread.} =
  let (mainChannel, responseChannel) = ch
  while true:
    let s = mainChannel.recv
    if s == nil:
      break
    echo s
    responseChannel.send(true)
  responseChannel.send(false)

proc main() =
  var
    mainChannel = newSharedChannel[string]()
    responseChannel = newSharedChannel[bool]()
    th: TThread[(SharedChannel[string], SharedChannel[bool])]
  createThread(th, someThread, (mainChannel, responseChannel))
  for i in 0..2:
    echo("main thread send: " & $i)
    mainChannel.send($i)
    if not responseChannel.recv:
      break
  mainChannel.send(nil)
  joinThread(th)
  close(mainChannel)
  close(responseChannel)

main()
```

Output:

```
main thread send: 0
0
main thread send: 1
1
main thread send: 2
2
```

---

### One more step, solution to this question:

```
import os, threadpool, macros

template spawnBackgroundJob(t: typedesc, chan:ptr TChannel[t], iter: expr): stmt {.immediate.}=
  block:
    proc threadFunc(channel: ptr TChannel[t]) {.thread.} =
      echo "Thread is starting"

      for i in iter:
        echo "Sending ", i
        channel[].send(i)

    channel[].open()

    var thread: TThread[ptr TChannel[t]]
    createThread(thread, threadFunc, chan)
    #joinThread(thread)


# example use in some main thread:
iterator testJob(): int =
  yield 0
  sleep(500)
  yield 1
  sleep(500)
  yield 2

var channel: ptr TChannel[int]
channel = cast[ptr TChannel[int]](allocShared0(sizeof(TChannel[int])))
spawnBackgroundJob(type(int), channel, testJob())

for i in 1 .. 10:
  sleep(200)
  echo channel[].peek()

channel[].close()
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that is the only problem here. At least, according to this answer, I would guess that [this](https://gist.github.com/bluenote10/d516ba98c5b1fb1bb8a2) should work. I also wasn't able to use Jehan's answer to solve my actual problem of running an iterator in a background thread.

Comment: @bluenote10 Jehan's answer is for Nim 0.11.3, rename TThread to Thread and TChannel to Channel. I paste a version for Nim 0.11.2 here, which should work.

Comment: The problem is that I could not get it to work with closure iterators. Since my anytime algorithms are closures I cannot simply put them into a global `proc someThread` like in this example.

Comment: @bluenote10 [Here](https://gist.github.com/rogercloud/d2ec8ef6d683b5b6804f) is a walk around for your case.

Comment: Nice, this seems to work just fine, thanks a lot! Would you mind to put this code into your answer instead of Jehans example? This would be more on-topic, and would provide everything to fully answer the question.